# The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: /usr/local/bin/cc is not a full path to an existing compiler tool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, ros

I know there are a lot of similar questions on the internet but I tried everything. But nothing works Idk what i am doing wrong.

```
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /usr/local/bin/cc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
```

I can find gcc, g++ files under usr/bin but in the error, it searches for the compiler on usr/local/bin.

```
set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/cc")
```

Even I changed the path in my CMake list for the compiler. Still no luck and by the way I am using ros1 and ubuntu. and i facing this error when i am trying to catkin_make my workspace.

Comment: The error message shows the path `/c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe`, which is not what you write in the title `/usr/local/bin/cc`. So, is it **actual** error message or not? If it is, then it suggests that you work on Windows/MinGW. In that case, why do you tag the question with "Ubuntu"? Please, provide more details about your problem, and make sure these details are **actual** ones.

Comment: It almost sounds like you have some kind of shell (git bash possibly) in windows, meant to ssh to your Ubuntu machine for development but forgot to and so are accidentally running locally on Windows?

Comment: Actually by reinstalling the GCC and cc. the previous error MinGW has been sorted out now I getting the error saying   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /usr/local/bin/cc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool